# Related to procedural calls and assembly language

Tags: c, assembly

I was going through some concepts of C when I came across this:

```
int add (int a, int b)
{
return a+b;
}

int main()
{
int a,b;
a = 3;
b = 4;
int ret = add(a,b);
printf("Result: %u\n", ret);
exit(0);
}
```

The assembler code generated for it as follows:

```
<main>:

1: push ebp

2: mov ebp, esp

3: sub esp, 0x18

4: mov eax, 0x0
```

.........(some more code but not relevant to the question)

The question I want to ask is why in the 3rd step value of stack pointer(esp) decreased by 24(0x18).

Comment: It's moving the stack pointer to the new stack frame.

Answer (score 3):

It's making room for six 4-byte ints on the stack.  The exact usage of these depends on the compiler and architecture, but these definitely include one each for `a`, `b`, and `ret`.

Incidentally, when I try this code on my MacBook Pro (x86, 64-bit, SnowLeopard) with gcc 4.2.1, it makes room for *eight* 4-byte ints.  In addition to the above, these include one for storing the value of `eax` prior to the calls to `add()` and `printf()`, since the results of each are returned in it (apparently due to the "cdecl" calling convention).  The layout on my machine looks like this:

```
-32:  unused
-28:  unused
-24:  unused
-20:  stores eax prior to each function call
-16:  ret
-12:  b
 -8:  a
 -4:  unused (potentially return value for main())
 ----------------
  0:  original base pointer
```

My guess is that the first unused slot at -4 is for a potential return value for `main()`.  I somewhat confirmed this by replacing `exit()` with `return -1;`.  In that case, it allocated two ints on the stack at -4 and -8 for a duplicate copy of the return value.  (This seems to be my compiler's way, as `add()` also duplicated the return value.)

For the other 3 unused slots, my guess is my compiler is trying to align on 8-byte boundaries (at least).  That doesn't explain why it added another 8 bytes (two unused ints) to the top of the stack though.  (I'm not really sure what's going on there -- maybe it prefers to align on 16-byte boundaries?)

Your compiler is probably aligning things differently (and potentially using some other calling convention and/or optimizing as well).

Comment: Thanks. And yes you are correct it is allocating memory for 6 integers. 3 for a,b and ret. 2 for the parameters main() is going to pass to add(), and 1 for main's return value. 
Though I am on a 32bit machine, the map is similar on my machine. The unused one's are there because of stack alignment probably. I guess the stack's frames should be aligned at 4 bytes(or 2 bytes, depending on the architecture)boundary.
Is your processor Intel too?

Comment: @Varun Yes, it's Intel.  Just out of curiosity, what compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc 4.4.3 on backtrack linux kernel 2.6

Comment: Just in case you are looking for more information on how stack behaves in intel architecture, I found this document quite useful in that respect : www.cse.unl.edu/~goddard/Courses/CSCE351/IntelArchitecture/IntelInterupts.pdf

Comment: Thanks! (I used to know this stuff fairly well, long ago.  But it's good to have a reference like this for my fading memories!) I see that section 28.2.2 answers the alignment questions.

Comment: And its always handy in debugging too!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler stores the return address of the function, the temporaries used in the function and the parameters passed to the function before transferring the control to the function call. All these are stored in the stack frame and hence the stack-pointer is decremented. I'm not sure why it decrements `sp` by `0x18` (probably you are on a 64bit machine hence 3(two temporaries+one return address) * 8 byte(64bit) ::= 0x18)